# How payments to multiple ethereum public address can be routed to single private keys?

Tags: addresses, private-key

I'm using coinbase commerce for accepting ethereum payments. Each time the user opens the link (for example [this](https://commerce.coinbase.com/checkout/1629662e-8a2e-4e10-a53e-615b7ecfc734)), they are asked for payment with different ethereum address. I made a mock payment of small amount acting as a 2 different payer ([this](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa717ee5b1fbd8f35647d05906a5db8a95753d918b50ce84a10caac1d4285f014) & [this](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x5df064c378384514423418fdebc3053c9381a5227985a9cf98a0ef866d7738f8)). Upon payment got mined on ethereum blockchain, it got reflected in my coinbase commerce account.

Subsequently, I imported the 12 key phase from coinbase commerce account to JAXX wallet and both the payments are reflected in the wallet despite totally different public address in wallet itself. Now, if I visit my JAXX wallet ethereum address etherscan page ([link](https://etherscan.io/address/0xf566f7ab7986506c16c07e7f9ff26e9cf6476b4e)), there's no payment against this address.

**Ques)** How is it possible to pay to some other address and it got credited to different ethereum address and what mechanism does coinbase commerce is using to accept payment with new ethereum address each time?

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure, but my guess is that Coinbase commerce is using the 12 word mnemonic to generate the many addresses (mnemonics aren't 1-to-1 with addresses, they can generate many addresses). Jaxx probably searches all the addresses for balances and shows them as one wallet.